# How to let the figure be displayed completely when we plot using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I plot using the following code in MATLAB. But the figure cannot be displayed completely as the picture shows below (the legend is hidden). What kind of parameters should I change to let the figure be shown completely?

[image]

```
clear;
clc;
close all;
y_lim = 1.5e9;
front_size = 20;
front_size2 = 16;
leg_font = 18;
leg_font2 = 12;
white_x = 0.06;
white_y = 0.105;
size_y = 0.87;
size_x = 0.9;

time_comp = figure('Name','Time Comparison');
set (time_comp,'Position',[0,0,700,500]);
hold on;

t = [6.335, 592.26, 2978, 19553.09, 736377, 2310000, 5808011.95, 1067732740];
time = [t; t; t; t];

box on
ylim([1 y_lim]);
bar_time = bar(time,'group','LineWidth',1,'BarWidth',1);
set(gca,'yscale','log');
xlabel_name = {'Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4'};
set(gca,'xtick', 1:1:4,'xticklabel', xlabel_name, 'FontSize', front_size2);
ylabel('Running time (in msec)', 'FontSize', front_size2);
set(gca,'position',[white_y white_x size_y size_x])

set(bar_time(1),'DisplayName','Method1');
set(bar_time(2),'DisplayName','Method2');
set(bar_time(3),'DisplayName','Method3');
set(bar_time(4),'DisplayName','Method4');
set(bar_time(5),'DisplayName','Method5');
set(bar_time(6),'DisplayName','Method6');
set(bar_time(7),'DisplayName','Method7');
set(bar_time(8),'DisplayName','Method8');

legend_time = legend(bar_time(1:8), 'Location','Northwest');
set(legend_time,'YColor',[1 1 1],'XColor',[1 1 1], 'Position',[1.005 0.045 0.155 0.926],'FontSize', leg_font2);
```

Comment: does reducing `size_x` help?

Comment: @pseudoDust The variable name may be confusing. `size_x` controls the top margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position property of legend takes normalized value to the aspect of current figure size. Four-element vector of the form `[left, bottom, width, height]` defined the size and location of your legend.

Imagining the size of your figure is 1, the position you set for your legend `[1.005 0.045 0.155 0.926]` is very tall and out of figure's display boundary. You have a number a approaches to resolve this issue.

1. Set a new position. Use values that is rather smaller and well-placed at the corner. This solution is usually not ideal because you have to experiment various times to your satisfaction.
2. Increase figure size. By setting new size of your figure, the problem can sometimes be solved. You may use `set(gcf,'Position',[0 0 800 600])` to gain more space to accommodate you legend. This solution may be convenient but not ideal to use alone if you have a lot of groups to display in one graph. We can, however, use this option to fine-tune our final production.
3. Use `Location` and `Orientation` property. Matlab already has several good preset locations. Why not let Matlab give you a hand so we can focus on other more important staff? `Location` properties with ***Outside*** values is especially helpful. In some cases that vertical legend display does not fit the figure, we can set the `Orientation` property to `horizontal`.

Let try replace the following code for you last line

```
set(legend_time,'FontSize', leg_font2,'Orientation','vertical','Location','EastOutside','Box','off');
```

or we can combine method 2 and 3 in different way with horizontal orientation.

```
set (time_comp,'Position',[0,0,1000,500]);
set(legend_time,'FontSize', leg_font2, 'Orientation', 'Horizontal', 'Location', 'northoutside','Box', 'off');
```

By the way, you may found more clues using their well-written documentation [Legend Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend-properties.html)

Comment: It works after I set `size_y = 0.74;` `set (time_comp,'Position',[0,0,800,450]);` `set(legend_time,'FontSize', leg_font2,'Orientation','vertical','Location','EastOutside','Box','off', 'Position',[0.846 0.045 0.155 0.926]);`. And many thanks to @Noel Segura

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting the properties of the legend, the value of `'position'` you are defining it as `[1.005 0.045 0.155 0.926]`, the values are normalized to the size of the plot, that means that 1.005 is going to be slightly outside of your plot. Modify this value and you should be good

---

Edit: also change the value of your `size_y` if you want to avoid overlapping

Answer (score 1):

To things that come to mind:

-1st) You should check if the legend's `position` is indeed normalized, so you can use the 0-1 range in the figure.

-2nd) You may want to squeeze the rest of the graphic by changing the `ActivePositionProperty` to `'OuterPosition'` and then change the `OuterPosition` property according to your will. This should neatly resized the plot and provide space to show the legend

I hope it clears some things for you.